# Pearson correlation over subsamples compared to the whole sample

Tags: statistics

I work on 'real-life data' and to simplify, I have a sample of 10.000 observations of two variables $X$ and $Y$ with a categorical variable $C$ that is either $C=0$ or $C=1$.

When I look for the pearson correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ over the whole data, I get $0.35$. But when I differentiate data with $C=0$ from data with $C=1$ I get coefficients of $0.08$ and $0.32$ respectively.

Is it something that one would expect ? What is the intuition behind that ? Is there some kind of weighted sum behind these results ?

Note that if I look for the Spearman's rank correlation coefficient (suited to non-linear relationships) I get similar results.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of your data ($Var(X).$ $Var(Y),$ $P(C = 0),$ etc.) it is difficult to know what to expect. However, correlations on smaller samples are more variable than correlations for larger ones. So maybe there is a significant difference between $r=.08$ and $r=.32$ and maybe not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was looking for something like a general rule regarding the link between correlation of a sample and the correlation over subsamples.